# 10th Anniversary of Beer, Wine & Spirits SE!

Tags: discussion, featured

In January Beer, Wine, and Spirits SE turned 10 years old. Congratulations on asking, answering, voting, and building this community for a whole decade!

Whenever a Stack Exchange site turns 10 we like to celebrate by encouraging users to reflect on their experiences here.

How did you first discover the site? Do you have a favorite question or answer? Any funny anecdotes or other insights that you would like to share? We want to hear it all!